# TypeError: 'Logger' object is not callable

Tags: python, oop, logging

I have tool, where some classes with inheritance used.

This my first big OOP based tool, and I'm little bit confused with classes initialization.

A lot of code below, to make this **Q** more clear.

Short inheritance tree:

```
- RDSmanager(object)
    - Options(RDSmanager)
    - AutoEnv(RDSmanager)
    - UnityXMLgenerator(RDSmanager)
```

Exactly logger class is:

```
class Logger(object):

    def __init__(self, rdsmanager_localpath):

        """Create Logger"""

        self.rdsmanager_localpath = rdsmanager_localpath

        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(self.rdsmanager_localpath, 'logs')):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(self.rdsmanager_localpath, 'logs'))

    def logger(self, modname):

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(modname)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s  - %(filename)s[LINE:%(lineno)d] - %(name)s.%(funcName)s() - %(message)s')

        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        filehandler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(self.rdsmanager_localpath, 'logs', 'rdsmanager.log'))
        filehandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        filehandler.setFormatter(formatter)

        consolehandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        consolehandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        self.logger.addHandler(filehandler)
        self.logger.addHandler(consolehandler)
```

Main script `RDSmanager.py` contain:

```
from lib.local.rds_services import Logger
...

class RDSmanager(object):
    ...

    # path to current RDSmanager directory
    # used toi determine where files (generated XML, logs etc) c to store in
    rdsmanager_localpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    # global logger object
    logger = Logger(rdsmanager_localpath)
```

Next, I have two options - `-c` and `-D` in other class:

```
class Options(RDSmanager):

    """Main "selector" for passed options.
       For each option - appropriate Class.method() will be imported, initialized and called."""

    def getopts(self):
        ...
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

        # Unity options
        parser_unity = subparsers.add_parser('unity', help='Unity application options')
        parser_unity.set_defaults(func=self.handler_unity)
        ...
            parser_unity.add_argument('-c',
                                  '--confgen',
                                  action='store_true',dest='unity_confgen',
        ...
            parser_unity.add_argument('-D',
                                  '--deployauto',
                                  action='store_true',
                                  dest='unity_autoenv_deploy',
        ...

    def handler_unity(self, options_list):

        ...   

        if options_list.unity_confgen:
            self.logger.logger.info('Running Unity XML files generator.')
            from lib.unity.xml_config_generator import UnityXMLgenerator
            confgen = UnityXMLgenerator()
            # generate application's config.xml
            confgen.config_xml_generator()
            # generate XML files for each module with TAG == 'CLOUD'
            # see lib.unity.unity_services.UnityServices() docstring for details
            confgen.modules_xmls_generator()
        ...

        if options_list.unity_autoenv_deploy:
            self.logger.logger.info('Running developers AutoEnvironment deploy.')
            from lib.unity.autoenv.developers_auto_env import AutoEnv
            auto = AutoEnv()
            auto.deploy()
```

Next, each class run `logger` initialization, i.e.:

```
class UnityXMLgenerator(RDSmanager):

    def __init__(self):

        print(id(self.logger.logger))
        print(id(self.logger))

        # self.build_type = build_type

        # self.logger.logger(self.__class__.__name__)

        print('self.logger')
        print(self.logger)

        print('self.logger.logger')
        print(self.logger.logger)

        self.logger.logger(self.__class__.__name__)

        ...

class AutoEnv(RDSmanager):

    def __init__(self):

        # self.build_type = build_type

        self.logger.logger(self.__class__.__name__)
```

When `-c` option used (i.e. - when `class UnityXMLgenerator(RDSmanager)` initialized directly from `class Options(RDSmanager)`) - all works good:

> ```
> > RDSmanager.py unity -c
> RDSmanager started at 23, Sep 2015 at 14:38:57
> Running Unity XML files generator.
> 39816128
> 52831184
> self.logger
> <lib.local.rds_services.Logger object at 0x032623D0>
> self.logger.logger
> <bound method Logger.logger of <lib.local.rds_services.Logger object at 0x032623D0>>
> ...
> ```

But - problem appears, when `class UnityXMLgenerator(RDSmanager)` called from `class AutoEnv(RDSmanager)`'s method:

```
def mkconfig(self):
    ...
    confgen = UnityXMLgenerator()
    ...
```

And run:

> ```
> > RDSmanager.py unity -D
> RDSmanager started at 23, Sep 2015 at 14:43:16
> Running developers AutoEnvironment deploy.
> Story NG-5859-developers-auto-env-build-config status checked - OK
> 39011216
> 52678608
> self.logger
> <lib.local.rds_services.Logger object at 0x0323CFD0>
> self.logger.logger
> <logging.Logger object at 0x02534390>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\Dropbox\RDS\rdsmanager_NG-1\RDSmanager.py", line 258, in <module>
>     rds.getopts()
>   File "D:\Dropbox\RDS\rdsmanager_NG-1\RDSmanager.py", line 176, in getopts
>     res.func(res)
>   File "D:\Dropbox\RDS\rdsmanager_NG-1\RDSmanager.py", line 228, in handler_unity
>     auto.deploy()
>   File "D:\Dropbox\RDS\rdsmanager_NG-1\lib\unity\autoenv\developers_auto_env.py", line 95, in deploy
>     self.mkconfig()
>   File "D:\Dropbox\RDS\rdsmanager_NG-1\lib\unity\autoenv\developers_auto_env.py", line 70, in mkconfig
>     confgen = UnityXMLgenerator()
>   File "D:\Dropbox\RDS\rdsmanager_NG-1\lib\unity\xml_config_generator.py", line 32, in __init__
>     self.logger.logger(self.__class__.__name__)
> TypeError: 'Logger' object is not callable
> ```

Questions is:

1. Why if I run `confgen = UnityXMLgenerator()` from `class Options(RDSmanager)` - object `self.logger.logger` is "`<bound method Logger.logger of <lib.local.rds_services.Logger object at 0x032623D0>>`" - but it's is "`<logging.Logger object at 0x02534390>`" - when it's initialized from `class RDSmanager(object)`'s child class class `AutoEnv(RDSmanager)` with `confgen = UnityXMLgenerator()`?
2. What exactly means "`<logging.Logger object at 0x02534390>`" and "`<bound method Logger.logger of <lib.local.rds_services.Logger object at 0x032623D0>>`"?
3. What I'm doing wrong here and how can I find solution for this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have both an instance attribute `logger` and a *method* called `logger`. You cannot have both:

```
def logger(self, modname):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(modname)
```

That instance attribute `logger` masks the method with the same name. Use a different name.